# 生成したUIColorのRGBA要素を変更する方法

Tags: ios, objective-c

`UIColor` のカテゴリを作っている時に、そのメソッドの中で `self(UIColor型)` の `RGBA` を変更する必要が出ました。
インスタンスを再生成せずに RGBA を変更する方法を教えてください。

Comment: タグ 'uicolor' を追加しました。 質問にサンプルコードを数行でも付けていただくと、回答者や、後から見た人が理解しやすくなりますよ。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

不可能です。

リファレンスには、以下の記述があるので明らかです。

> Color objects are immutable and so it is safe to use them from multiple threads in >your app.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/index.html

不変オブジェクトの、バグを引き起こしにくく、スレッド安全である性質から、
iOS SDKのいくつかのクラスは、不変オブジェクトとして実装されています。

したがって今回のケース、カテゴリを作成するにあたっても、
自身のデータを変更することなく、新しいUIColorを戻り値等で返す実装が推奨されます。

Answer (score 0):

`UIColor` はイミュータブルなので、変更はできず、作り直すことになります。 典型的には以下のような形になるでしょう。

```
CGFloat red, green, blue, alpha ;

BOOL ok = [ myOldColor getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha ];
if ( !ok ) { 
  // 色空間が RGB ではないなどの理由で取得失敗
}

// HERE: red, gree, blue, alpha を変更する

UIColor *myNewColor = [ UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha ];
```

参考: [UIKit Framework Reference > UIColor Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/index.html)